# Looking for an old novel called "The Reconstructed Man"

Tags: story-identification, novel

Looking for an old novel called "The Reconstructed Man". The story is about a wimpy man with overbearing wife who is abducted by aliens who reconstruct him "better" and install a recording device to capture all his experiences for a period of time.

We follow his experiences until they pick him up again. We learn how power corrupts etc.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Please try to add anything that may help identification. Review this [**checklist**](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337). When did you read it?  What language was it in? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Answer (score 18):

[The Reassembled Man](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?8785) by Herbert D. Kastle.

I'm sure I have a copy somewhere because I remember the story but I cannot find it in the chaos that is my book collection. So [here is a summary I found on the web](http://glorioustrash.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/the-reassembled-man.html):

> Our “hero” is Ed Berner, a 38 year-old sap who has been beaten down by life. Married to a shrew, the father of two prepubescent kids, Ed makes a moderate living as a copywriter at a Manhattan ad agency.

The aliens are the *Druggish*.

> The aliens (who initially speak in beatnik, having assumed it was the standard Earth language from their research) inform Ed that he’s been chosen to be their “recorder” of life on Earth. They wanted an average guy living an average life, and Ed fit the bill. In exchange they will grant him his wishes; anything Ed has previously longed for will be given him.

You don't say what you mean by *old*, but the book was published in 1964.